# MySQL: Best way to check if user has permission by role

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, inner-join

I'm building a small permission system, but unfortunately I'm no SQL expert by any means.

In this system I've decided to give all users a role and then assign specific permissions to the roles. My current database tables look like this:

[image]

My question is: What's the best way to check if a given `User.id` as a permission, by providing a `Permission.permission_name` value. I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT EXISTS (

    SELECT perm.id

    FROM `User` userr

    INNER JOIN `Role_Permission` connectionc
    ON userr.role_id = connectionc.role_id

    INNER JOIN `Permission` perm
    ON connectionc.permission_id = perm.id

    WHERE userr.id = 1
    AND perm.permission_name LIKE 'doStuff'

) as userHasPermission
```

It works, but, from my understanding joining is expensive and that query is joining the content of 3 tables and then filtering what it needs.

Link to sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ed7b/1

Thank you.

Comment: A bit confusing "INNER JOIN `Role` role ON userr.id = role.id". Shouldn't that be "INNER JOIN `Role` role ON userr.role_id = role.id". IMO I don't see any reason why joining 'roles' is table is necessary.

Comment: @JA you're right. ;) Just edited.

Comment: SQL seems to be correct. Could you initiate/provide an sqlfiddle.com please?

Comment: @JA http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ed7b/1 , yeah the code is correct, I was misreading something in another place. The original question remains. Who can I optimize the query? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's much place to optimise the query. From the real world scenario, no matter how big the user table is, role and permission table shouldn't exceed 3 digit and therefore, role_permission would not exceed 998001 records. If all the right columns are indexed properly, I believe, the sql will be quite fast (<0.1 sec). You can always check EXPLAIN do check if there's any bottlenecks.

(Off topic)
Alternatively, having worked on a similar project recently, there are few choices out there to improve speed fetching from 'finite' no. records.

- Memory: You can choose to save all these relevant tables/data in memory (as opposed to disk) to minimise I/O related latency.
- NoSQL: You can either choose a NoSQL solution like mongoDB and/or implement noSQL-like structure in MySql to eliminate Joins.
- Redis: Arguably, the best solution if you'd like to think outside the box. Fastest of all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much room for optimization, not without compromising the normalization of the database. Just make sure that you have the appropriate indexes in place.

Some alternatives would be:

- Store the index name in the role permission table, thus requiring one less join. It will be not normalized, but this may be acceptable if permissions rarely change and you really need maximum performance.
- Do not use integer ids for the permissions, instead, use their name as unique identifier. Then you don't need the table `Permission` at all, unless you need to add some attribute to them (but that would still allow you to check for a permission with only one join).

You should also consider how often do you need to run this query. Depending on you requirements, it may be acceptable to read all user permissions only when the user enters the system and store them on variables during the whole session; in this case you do not need so high a performance for the query. Or you could initially load not the permissions but the role, which would mean one less join on the query.